# Multiple versions of Sencha Ext Core in the same page

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, extjs

It's possible to deploy multiple versions of Ext Core JS Library in the same web page?

jQuery uses the **.noConflict()** function for example.

Thanks,
Wiliam.

---

I wanna let users to insert our widgets into they pages, but I must use a specific version of Ext Core without overriding the version that the user is using in his page.

Comment: Just to note, jQuery's `.noConflict()` is not a good example, it enables jQuery to work with **other** libraries that use `$`, multiple versions of jQuery in the same page absolutely causes issues with or without `.noConflict()`.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why this would be necessary. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If I want to add code in another web page, for example, a search box, I wanna use my own Ext Core version independently of the version that the user uses.

Comment: jQuery's noConflict is designed to allow other libraries ALONG WITH multiple versions of jQuery (read the documentation; it's the main reason you can supply a boolean value to the method). Multiple versions of jQuery is very possible and easy to do and would NOT absolutely cause issues. Not sure why everyone is so hostile...sometimes this is truly necessary.